# How to select rows with certain missing pattern?

Tags: r, missing-data, r-mice

So I have a dataset that contains a lot of missing values. I want to separate the data of different missing patterns. I found the package 'mice' which is very handy in summarizing the missing value patterns. However, when I want to select the rows with a certain missing pattern, the number of selected rows is much fewer than the count as missing pattern matrix suggests.

My code is as follows.

To get the missing pattern:

```
library(mice)
# md.pattern returns a matrix, I convert the matrix into a data frame with the first column as its frequency in the data frame 
pattern = md.pattern(data)
freq = dimnames(pattern)[[1]][-nrow(pattern)] 
pattern = data.frame(pattern[1:nrow(pattern)-1, 1:ncol(pattern)-1], row.names = NULL)
pattern$freq = freq
pattern = pattern[order(freq,decreasing = TRUE),]
```

However, when I try to count the missing patterns manually by a specific pattern in the `pattern`. The count is much smaller.

```
count = 0
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    # match the missingness by the entire row
    if (all(!is.na(data[i, names(data)[1:ncol(pattern)-1]]) == test[1,1:ncol(pattern)-1])){
        count = count +1
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea where goes wrong?
Thanks!

The data has a lot of variables(107 in total) and 70000+ observations. This code works well in the sample data `nhanes` in the `mice` package. But it just goes wrong in my data file.

For example:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  NA  3  5  2
NA  3 23  2  9
NA  3 90  7  5
3   3  2 34 NA
3  NA  2  1  3
4  NA  7  3  1
```

Comment: You have to provide some sample data for us to play with that is representative of your real data. At the moment, we have nothing to base any suggestions on.

Comment: @thelatemail I have uploaded a sample of the data file. Thanks!

Comment: *"Provide some sample data"* does not mean *"give us a link to a file of unknown origin so that we can click on it, see what format it is in, infer where the problems are, etc"*. Please reduce the problem to a small dataset and add that directly to this question. (This also helps somebody who might benefit from this question when the link you provide goes stale.)

Comment: ... and by *"add to this question"*, I suggest something like `dput(myvar)` or code use to actually create the data (e.g., a call to `data.frame`).

Comment: Please consider reading this: [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in r.

Answer (score 3):

Anyway, I checked the [original code](https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/blob/master/R/md.pattern.r) for `md.pattern` in `mice` package. It's based on Schafer's prelim.norm function, not row-by-row checking missing value pattern.

I found the `count` in `plyr` package really does the trick. I wrote this function to return the top `n` missing patterns in the dataset. `x` is the data frame. It works well in my case.

```
library(plyr)
miss.pattern <- function(x, topn) {
  # find missingness patterns, 1 represents missing
  r <- 1 * data.frame(is.na(x))
  pattern <- data.frame(count(r))
  pattern <- pattern[order(-pattern$freq),]
  return(pattern[1:topn,])
}
```